# Requests with lager than 1GB data fail after upgrading to Apache 2.4.54

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

Sending requests with larger than 1GB data always fail after upgrading to Apache 2.4.54.

In Apache 2.4.53 and older versions, the LimitRequestBody limit was set to unlimited. It seems that this has been changed in version 2.4.54, but I cannot find this information in the [change log](https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/CHANGES_2.4.54).

The only workaround we find is overwrite LimitRequestBody in Apache config files.

Is this intended behavior?
Plus, does anyone know where can you find the information about this change?

FYI: We use Apache via [official PHP Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), I don't know it is related to this behavior change though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the change was related to CVE-2022-30522, which was mentioned in changelog.

But the change itself is not mentioned, and was applied way too general IMHO.